# extract attributes of model from a list column in r

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

My data is a little bit complicated.So I'm using mtcars dataset to illustrate my issue.
Do lm for 4cyl car and glm otherwise. Save the models in a column called 'model'. 
Now I'm trying to extract the model class and put them in a different column.

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% 
    do (model = if (mean(.$cyl)==4) lm(mpg~wt, data=.) else glm(vs~wt, data=., family='binomial')) %>% 
    mutate(model.class=attributes(model)$class)
```

what I got is the error message below:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Column `model.type` must be length 1 (the group size), not 2
```

Anyone can help me with that? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The `class()` function is better than delving around attributes yourself. Because an object can have more than one class, the new column needs to be a list as well.

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% 
    do (model = if (mean(.$cyl)==4) lm(mpg~wt, data=.) else glm(vs~wt, data=., family='binomial')) %>% 
    mutate(model.class = list(class(model)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option to extract `class` information using the `map` function from the `purrr` package.

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  do (model = if (mean(.$cyl)==4) lm(mpg~wt, data=.) else glm(vs~wt, data=., family='binomial')) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(model.class = map(model, class))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
    cyl     model model.class
  <dbl>    <list>      <list>
1     4  <S3: lm>   <chr [1]>
2     6 <S3: glm>   <chr [2]>
3     8 <S3: glm>   <chr [2]>
Warning message:
glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```